# how to display all the items of array in label Xcode 8

Tags: arrays, label

I want to ask how to display all the items of the array in label. I'm using Xcode 8. I saw a teacher uses:

```
LabelName.text = "\{ArrayName}"
```

but it's not works in my xcode, so

I have tried

```
for i in 0..<ArrayName.count
    {
                    LabelName.text = ArrayName[i]

    }
```

but it's only show the last item. Thank you xD

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that, I made a mistake with "(" and "{"

It must be this

```
Label.text = "\(ArrayName)"
```

but I want to ask how to display each item in each line?
Thank you anyway xD